Water Leak from Sink for 9 hours, anything further necessary?
After replacing a bathroom sink on 2nd floor around 8pm, we didn’t tighten one of the water lines all the way and didn’t realize it. Around 5AM the downstairs ceiling had a leak and the fire alarm just adjacent to the went spot actually went off, probably because it detected the moisture (the fire alarm can go off if it gets water damage, and I suspect it did, will replace it). We immediately noticed the ceiling and fixed the leak.
Do we let this dry out, or should we have to cut into the drywall? Rent fans to dry it out? We live in Florida, so hot and humid.


Or this? Can water-damaged drywall be repaired, or does it have to be replaced?

Or this? Do I need to do anything after a bathroom flooding? How can I prevent it in future?

Or this? What should I do immediately after a clean water flood to minimize damage?

The high humidity could be an issue. However I'll assume you have your AC on so it will draw the moisture down. Not a problem.
I live in Fla. too and have run across this type of occurrence. Her are some "rules of thumb" for when you have leaks.
Anything like rain, flood water or wastewater; the affected areas should be opened up. Drywall and insulation removed and any wood, concrete, etc. allowed to dry thoroughly. An application of 50/50 bleach water should be applied to kill off any pathogens. ( This is not your case so you're ok.)
Leaks from potable water; The chlorine in the water will kill any pathogens to keep mold at bay for a relative short time. (< 24 hours). If the area is dry within that time you are ok.  However if there is insulation in a wall that will hold moisture the wall/ ceiling should be opened up and the insulation removed and replaced when the area is dry.  Areas that have been subject to water for longer than 24 hours should be opened and allowed to dry. ( A leak not noticed and remaining for a longer time. (>24 hrs) It's not a bad idea to assist with fans. The rules for the rain, wastewater should then be followed.
You have a situation where potable water wet an area and you found it relatively quickly.  If there is no insulation in the ceiling and it has dried in 24 hours you are ok there. The area behind the sink is what would concerne me.  I would place a fan under the sink and examine for areas that are still damp.  If the ceiling still shows a damp area after 24 hours it would be prudent to remove the sink to have a look behind and under. Otherwise the damp condition can grow mold.
